# Count distinct non-blank codes in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data:

```
ID Code1 Code2 Code3  
1    c1    c2   
2    c1    c2    c3
1    c1    c2
```

I need to do a code count by ID in one single query without writing sub-queries. This is because I am running this through millions of rows. Writing sub-queries will give me "temp created too long ago" type of error. I tried the following in SQL, but it is still counting the blanks. The correct code count should be 5, but the query indicates 6. How can I count distinct non-blank code by ID?

```
COUNT(DISTINCT ID||DECODE(CODE1,null,0,1)) +   
COUNT(DISTINCT ID||DECODE(CODE2,null,0,1))+   
COUNT(DISTINCT ID||DECODE(CODE3,null,0,1))
```

Comment: What do you mean with distinct?  count the distinct values in one row?, i.E. row c1 c2 c2 adds 2 to the count?

Comment: @Turo that means ID1 has 2 codes, and ID2 has 3 codes. So, the total is 5 codes. The reason why to I used distinct is because there may be duplicate IDs.. For each unique ID, I want to count how many non-blank codes associated with it..

Comment: more confusion: what is the desired count for this two rows:  1 c1 c2 c3, and 1 c1 c2

Comment: @Turo Sorry. The correct count would be a total of 5, not 6.. My query is counting the blanks (for example, c3 for 1 is blank. It shouldn't be counted towards the total)

Comment: @Turo - I made changes to my example. Added one more row of ID1 with duplicate codes. But this should not change the total code count. The correct total should still be 5 codes. I could get this right if I utilize sub-query. But, I need to write this all in one single query. So couldn't get it right..

Comment: what does this || operator mean,i know SQL Server,i tried to search with same operator ,but no results

Comment: @TheGameiswar - Distinct by multiple columns

Comment: @Futochan:Thanks,any links for this

Comment: Did you find a suitable solution to this question? Could you mark an answer as accepted or leave a comment?

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID, Code1, Code2, Code3 ) AS  
SELECT 1, 'c1', 'c2', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'c1', 'c2', 'c3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'c1', 'c2', NULL FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT ID || Code ) AS num_id_codes
FROM   table_name
UNPIVOT ( code FOR name IN ( Code1, Code2, Code3 ) );
```

**Output**:

```
NUM_ID_CODES
------------
           5
```

Comment: Going to try this. Dumb Question. Does the where statement does before the unpivot or after?

Comment: Probably should have mentioned that ID and CodeX both came from a separate table. If I were to use unpivot, my query will have sub-query, which will run into error.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to count a particular code only once per *id*, then:

```
select   count(code)
from (
    select   id, Code1 as code
    from     tbl
    union
    select   id, Code2
    from     tbl
    union
    select   id, Code3
    from     tbl
)
```

Note that `union` eliminates duplicate id, code combinations, and `count(code)` only counts non-null values.

Comment: I wasn't clear on my question. I actually have a lot of dups. I edited my example above. The first query you provided will also count the dups in, which I don't want. And I do not need the counts per value of ID..

Comment: Please define duplicate: the whole record or the value `c1`? Because in comments you replied that the count should be 5 for `1 c1 c2 c3, and 1 c1 c2`, but clearly `c1` and `c2` are duplicate.

Comment: sorry. Duplicate ID. It doesn't matter if we have duplicates in codes. We first look at only unique ID, and then count how many codes.

Comment: `UNION ALL` does **not** eliminate duplicates - you want `UNION` (without the `ALL`) for that but it will also include the `NULL` rows.

Comment: Ooops, you are right! fixed union issue and null issue.

Comment: It is one query, with a sub query. What is the problem with having sub queries?

Comment: My query takes days to run. So it would run into "snapshot too old" error

Answer (score 0):

This is a manual un-pivot that only scans your table once. The CROSS APPLY will force the sub-query to be merged into the main one using nested loops. If the number of distinct values is small enough with the real data, hint the optimiser to use a HASH GROUP BY to count the distinct values if it is not already, saving the expensive temp table sort.

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id||codex)
FROM
  TABLE_NAME
    CROSS APPLY
  ( SELECT code1 codex FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT code2 codex FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT code3 codex FROM DUAL
  )
WHERE codex IS NOT NULL`